# How to use a comma properly

Tags: sentence, commas, syntactic-analysis

Hello I am what I would consider under educated in a way. I never studied much in school. Either way I am here now.Never fully understanding when to use a comma. My lack of knowledge often scares me away from using them in fear of using them inappropriately. When do I have to use a comma? I know I can use them to set off starting words or phrases but I do not know the actual rules to that. Maybe I over think it but it can be upsetting. Also is the rule use it between two independent but related clauses only if you use a fanboy? If you are connecting an independent with a dependent clause then you do not need one, but if you choose to use one do not use a fanboy?

Fanboy = for, and, nor, but, or, yet

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. This is a little broad, the kind of question you can read about in a grammar book or on a grammar site, like [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/search/site/comma). Please take the tour and visit the help center to learn a bit about the site. ') (Oh, and my guess is you studied better than you think. I never heard of *fanboy*. Cool!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the rule of thumb my eighth grade English teacher taught me, before I mastered when to use a comma.

> Read the sentence, out loud and multiple times, if necessary, and any place that you have a little pause while reading is a place where a comma is probably needed, or at least helpful.

This should work most of the time, but it is not perfect.